# Print to video Ip-address-from socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip, ip-address

I wish I could create a small application that I print screen the IP address to which the socket is connected.

I'm trying this code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

 Socket s = new Socket();
 String host ="10.10.20.xxxx";

    try {
        s.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, 6000 ), 1000 );

        InetAddress inetAddress = s.getLocalAddress();
        String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
        //Now, I would like to have printed out the IP-address
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ip , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //But nothing happens
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But, I have never seen printed the IP address,
                                                                                         If is necessary I can create a TextView and inside-It put the string ip.
Where am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think I don't get it. You're connecting to the IP 10.10.20.X if the connection succeced then you already got the address 10.10.20.X. What else do you want to know?

Comment: Hi ja_mesa, thanks for you comment,
You have a reason, I have the IP-address, but I would like to be a method (socket) to tell me what IP they are connected.
I need to practice with getLocalAddres() etc, but I don't konow how manage these methods. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my delay. Once you open (connect) a socket you have several methods from that object. `socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() `and `socket.getLocalAddress()`, they give you exactly what you're looking for. If you need an example, just let me know.

Comment: no problem ja_mesa, thanks for your help.If you give me an example, I can accept your solution as desired(accept answer): 
And I understand better : D 
kind regards !!

Comment: P.s. sorry for my delay to ...thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ulyssessPax:

When you `connect`/`accept` to/from a device via TCP sockets, you have the following method from that socket:

`socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString()`
it gives you the remote IP address and the port number where it's connected. For example: 192.168.1.30:6000

`socket.getLocalSocketAddress()`
it gives you the local IP address and the port number where it has established the connection. For example: 10.0.2.15:54471

Hope it's what you're looking for.